# How to generate many new columns in pandas Dataframe in a convenient way?

Tags: pandas, data-analysis

Suppose I have a Dataframe `df` of many columns now, and I'm trying to generate a large number of variable. The naive way I think is

```
df['new_var_1'] = df['var_1'] + df['var_2']
df['new_var_2'] = df['var_2'] / (df['var_3'] + df['var_4'])
df['new_var_3'] = ...
...
df['new_var_100'] = ...
```

However, repeating inputing `df[]` is a boring work, and I wonder whether there is a convenient way to generate such variables without repeating input `df[]` so many times, just like what I do in R:

```
df <- transfrom(df,
    new_var_1 = var_1 + var_2,
    new_var_2 = var_2 / (var_3 + var_4),
    new_var_3 = ...
    ...
    new_var_100 = ...
)
```

Since the name of the DataFrame I used in my project is not so short as `df`, it's important to find a better way to generate new variables. Thanks for your answer!

I have searched for long time to find such way, but failed. All answers generate variables in a similar way.

Comment: Use pandas assign method

Comment: I've tried `pd.assign()`, but it doesn't help much, since variables at the right of equal sign still need to call as `df['...']` or lambda function? Thanks for your answer too.

Comment: That's unavailable in python... The other option might be to use pd.query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas's [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval) with one expression per line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], columns=['var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3', 'var_4'])

df.eval('''
    new_var_1 = var_1 + var_2
    new_var_2 = var_2 / (var_3 + var_4)
    new_var_3 = 3
    new_var_100 = 100
    '''
)
```

Output;

```
   var_1  var_2  var_3  var_4  new_var_1  new_var_2  new_var_3  new_var_100
0      1      2      3      4          3   0.285714          3          100
1      5      6      7      8         11   0.400000          3          100
```

Comment: That is what I need! But it seems to work for DataFrame of only one row?

Comment: ```Python
mini_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'var_1': [1, 2],
    'var_2': [3, 6],
    'var_3': [5, 4]
})

mini_df.eval("""
    new_var_1 = var_1 + var_2,
    new_var_2 = var_1 * var_3 + var_2
""")
```
Code like this will raise an Error.

Comment: As said in my answer, you must use one expression per line in the string, not comma separated expressions. I had forgotten to remove the commas from the code In copied from your answer ;)